# Show subreport if main report empty

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2010 database which has a report. The report takes two values from a form to filter the results. The report is comprised of a main report and a sub-report.

I am having a problem however in that if the main report returns no records, the sub-report doesn't show up even if *does* infact contain records. I have put the contents of the input variables onto the sub report so I can see that the sub report is getting the correct input variables. Alas, it doesn't show anything if the main report is blank?

Is there anyway to always show a sub-report if the main report is empty?

Comment: You have to make sure at least ONE record is always present in the main report query. Maybe use a union with an 'empty' row table?

Answer (score 0):

If you report depends on link child and master fields for the subform control, you can make this work by setting the link master field to the name of a control, rather than the name of a field. For example, let use say that you have a field called `AText`, which is bound to a control `AText`, the subform has link child and master fields:

```
  Link Master Fields: AText
  Link Child Fields:  AText
```

This is normal for a form created using a wizard. Now start tampering. Rename the control `Atext` to say, `txtAtext`, change the linke master field:

```
  Link Master Fields: txtAText
  Link Child Fields:  AText
```

And add a little code:

```
Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtAText.ControlSource = "=""abc"""
End Sub
```

Where the value "abc" is a value that occurs in the record source for the subform, so the subform will be populated with all "abc" records. Clearly you will have to change the above to suit your particular data.

Comment: Hi Remou,

Thanks for your input. I have added the extra field and the code in the "No Data" section. However it throws a runtime error "2191" "You cant set the control source property after the print preview has started".

I'm using the following to display the report:
DoCmd.OpenReport "PlanningList", acViewPreview, , "[Meeting Ref]='" & Me!txtSelectWeek & "'  AND  ([List Number]= '" & Me!txtList & "')"
'DoCmd.PrintOut
SendKeys "^p"

Is there anyway to set the field before Access tries to show it in print preview?

Comment: Is there anyway to use carriage returns on this site?

Everything seems to appear on one line in these comment boxes..?